# Statistical signifiance of uniform random generator

Tags: p-value, interpretation, random-generation

I'm writing an implementation of [Fortuna](https://www.schneier.com/academic/paperfiles/fortuna.pdf), and have implemented the core PRNG / DRBG which should produce a uniform distribution.
I've run a variety of statistical random test suites over the output ([Dieharder](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php), [TestU01](http://simul.iro.umontreal.ca/testu01/tu01.html), 
[RaBiGeTe](http://cristianopi.altervista.org/RaBiGeTe_MT/), [PractRand](http://pracrand.sourceforge.net/)) and there were enough border-line results that I'm slightly worried something is wrong.

My question is: statisticly, should I be worried by the results below? Are they acceptable from a statistical point of view if I'm expecting a uniform distribution?

The following tests have p less than 0.001 or more than 0.999:

- PractRand test `[Low1/8]FPF-14+6/16:(3,14-0)`: p = 0.99929 (or 1-7.1e-4 on the raw results) ([link](https://blog.ligos.net/images/Building-A-CRNG-Terninger-4-Random-Tests/practrand-256GB.out.txt))
- RaBiGeTe_MT test `Short blk 4_16`: p = 0.0008 ([link](https://blog.ligos.net/images/Building-A-CRNG-Terninger-4-Random-Tests/RaBiGeTe-table.png))
- RaBiGeTe_MT test `DFT 1`: p = 0.0005 ([link](https://blog.ligos.net/images/Building-A-CRNG-Terninger-4-Random-Tests/RaBiGeTe-pearson.png))
- Test U01 test `LongestHeadRun`: p = 0.00075 ([results link](https://blog.ligos.net/images/Building-A-CRNG-Terninger-4-Random-Tests/testu01-bigcrush.out.5.txt), [test definition - p127](http://simul.iro.umontreal.ca/testu01/guideshorttestu01.pdf))

For reference, PractRand produced 267 results, RaBiGeTe ~350, and TestU01 160.

[Link to blog post with full details of random tests](https://blog.ligos.net/2017-06-02/Building-A-CRNG-Terninger-4-Random-Tests.html)

For those who may not know, Fortuna defines its CPRNG as AES in counter mode. That is, the output is produced by encrypting a 16 byte counter (incremented after every encryption operation).

I'm concerned because given the author of Fortuna (Schneier) and use of the most popular block cypher in existence (AES), I was expecting all the test to pass with flying colours.
And **all** the test suites picked something up, not just one.

(And, being primarily a coder, I don't fully understand what the very small / large p results in these tests actually mean).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with RaBiGeTe_MT or TestU01, but all of your PractRand results are "normal". I will make the observation that you have not let PractRand run anywhere near long enough to uncover any systemic issues in a 128-bit RNG. [Even a 128-bit MCG](http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/128-bit-mcg-passes-practrand.html) (which has well known statistical flaws) passes the default 32 TB of PractRand testing. Such generators are simply too big to fail. At the other extreme a generator with 32 bits of state would be too small to pass, because it could generate no more than 16 GB of data before starting to repeat. So to answer your questions in the context of PractRand:

**statisticly, should I be worried by the results below?**

No, there is nothing to worry about as PractRand says all of your results are "normal" (ie. indistinguishable from random), but you would also need to let the testing run significantly longer to uncover systemic issues. I would expect a 128-bit CSPRNG to pass 32 TB of PractRand testing with flying colours, and a failure would most likely indicate either a "bad" seed value or an implementation issue.

**Are they acceptable from a statistical point of view if I'm expecting a uniform distribution?**

You should not be expecting a uniform distribution, because truly random data does not have a uniform distribution. Any generator which does have a uniform distribution will fail statistical tests long before reaching it's full period because it will be obvious that it could not be a random distribution. For a uniform 128-bit generator, each 128-bit value can only be generated once per period, whereas with truly random data we would start expecting to see some duplicate values once enough numbers have been generated. Imagine you had a die where you had to roll each of the six numbers before you saw a repeat, or a coin that could not have multiple heads or tails in a row. You would not believe that it was truly random unless you saw some duplicates within a reasonable time frame.

The way that this is generally handled with RNGs is to output a number that is smaller than the state size. It is typical to see a 64-bit generator outputting 32-bit numbers, and see a 32-bit generator outputting 16-bit numbers. This solves the issue of too much uniformity to a degree, because with an n-bit uniform generator, you will see each value exactly to 2 ^ (n/2) times per period. Once you get far enough into the generator's period though, there comes a point where you would expect to see a particular value *more than* 2 ^ (n/2) times, and it is past this point where statistical tests will start to fail. I understand this is not an issue with Fortuna as reseeding takes place long before you get far enough into the underlying PRNG's period.

Comment: It is not clear to me how this gives an appropriate answer to the question.

Comment: PractRand says the result he's worried about is "normal", therefore there is nothing to worry about, it doesn't say "unusual", "suspicous", "VERY SUSPICIOUS", or "FAIL !!!!", or any of the other messages that indicate an anomalous result.

His second question demonstrates a misunderstanding of the nature of random data. The goal of a PRNG is to be indistinguishable from random data. A stream of truly random data does not have a uniform distribution, and he should therefore not expect one.

Comment: Using Yahtzee as an analogy, the probabilities of getting various combinations on a single roll of five dice is:

Two of a kind: 69.44%
Three of a kind: 19.29%
Four of a kind: 1.93%
Five of a kind: 0.08%
Five different numbers: 9.26%

If you were to use a uniform RNG that could produce six values in it's period before starting to repeat, it would produce a repeating permutation on {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} but it could never generate a two, three, four, or five of a kind. So you could easily distinguish such an RNG from true randomness after a few numbers had been generated.

Comment: I agree with @Michael: you dismiss the low p-values out of hand without providing any real explanation or at least giving a reference to back up your assertion that it is "normal" for several components of a PRNG tester to have low p-values.  Parts of this answer very well could be correct, but until you can offer such backup for your opinion, it's not going to be convincing and many readers may go away wondering whether it's really right.

Comment: @whuber, the OP asks if he should be worried, and the tool is saying no because the result is "normal" (ie. indistinguishable from random). That's not my opinion it's the evaluation that the author of PractRand has hardcoded into his program. As I mentioned, he did not let the test run for long enough to truly uncover a flaw, and the p-value would change over the course of the test. The p-value he is concerned about is _specific to_ 256GB of tested data using _one specific seed_, and not multiple runs of the full 32 TB battery of tests over several seeds.

Comment: Most people would not view p-values less than 0.001 as indications of "normal" behavior.  Moreover, one would in general expect such p-values to get smaller as the amount of data increases: these are *early warnings* of potential non-uniform, non-independent behavior.

Comment: That's an unrealistic expectation, because with random data you expect the occasional blip on the radar that subsequently vanishes. That's why you need to test more and more data, because if the p-values do indeed get smaller as the amount of data increases, that's when you've uncovered a systemic flaw, and the earlier small p-values are indeed an early warning in such circumstances. [Here is an example](https://imgur.com/VxVRMte) of "blips on the radar" that subsequently vanished. [Here is an example](https://imgur.com/m071wLZ) of an "early warning" that became a test failure.

Comment: In the test failure example, note that magnitude of the p-values as the anomalies become more significant:
(1) p=1-3.3e-5 for "mildly suspicous".
(2) p=1-2.7e-6 for "suspicious".
(3) p=1-8.3e-15 for "FAIL !".

Comment: @Dean, if data is random, that doesn't mean it doesn't follow a uniform distribution.  Statistical randomness is according to some distribution, and PRNGs are usually designed to try to match a uniform distribution.  That is where the p-values come from.  Your point about fewer numbers than the period addresses this, so it's a point of clarification. (A more general sense of "random" is not something PRNG tests could test, it seems to me.)

Comment: I also want to say that I have been reading about PRNGs quite a bit recently (Knuth, other books, some articles), and it was only when I read your third paragraph that I finally understood clearly why one should use only a fraction of a PRNG's period.  Thank you.

Comment: @Mars, with a uniform dist. there is an equal chance that any possible number will be generated. The way PRNGs are often implemented though, that isn't the case. An oft used analogy is a bag filled with numbered balls. A uniform dist. can be modelled by drawing a ball, noting its number, then placing it back in the bag. The usual technique with PRNGs though, is akin to drawing a ball, noting it's number, but then putting it aside. After one draw, we no longer have a uniform dist.! With n balls and k draws, the draw chances are now 0% for k balls, and 1/(n-k) for the remaining (n-k) balls.

Comment: @Dean, you're absolutely right.  Otoh, you know that better PRNGs use a larger state than the number of possible outcomes (e.g. Mersenne Twister--not the best) has a 624-bit state for 32-bit numbers.  This makes it easier to better approximate a uniform distribution in any one subsequence of generated numbers, because the same number *can* appear more than once.  It's true that if you run through the whole period, at some point certain numbers will have been "used up", but the number of theoretically possible repetitions (up to $2^{592}$) in any reasonable number of trials is enormous.

Comment: @Mars, the two techniques that I've seen widely used are expanding state space (a la Mersenne Twister), and reseeding after using a much smaller fraction of the period (a la Fortuna). The 1st technique is more common (briefly covered in para 4 of my answer), while the 2nd has the benefit of higher throughput but the drawback of requiring more entropy for the reseed. More generally, if you're generating x bit numbers and want to generate 2^y numbers, you need at least (x+y) bits of of state to give a reasonable approximation of a true RNG with numbers drawn from a uniform distribution.

Comment: To expand on why we shouldn't expect a uniform distribution. If we roll a 6 sided die 12 times, how many times do we expect to see each number? If we are expecting a uniform distribution, we expect each number exactly twice. But this isn't what happens in reality. A number might occur anywhere between 0 and 12 times. Whilst we are drawing FROM a uniform distribution, we're actually expecting to see a binomial distribution in the sequence generated. For any given number the probabilities are: 11.22% for 0 times, 26.92% for 1 time, 29.61% for 2 times, 19.74% for 3 times, etc.

Comment: To model a typical PRNG implementation, imagine we have a bag with 72 balls in it, and there are 12 balls numbered "1", 12 numbered "2", etc. We draw 12 balls, each time noting down it's number then place it aside. In this case we're not expecting either a uniform dist. or binomial dist., but a hypergeometric dist. in the sequence generated. For any given number the probabilities are: 9.11% for 0 times, 26.77% for 1 time, 32.39% for 2 times, 21.17% for 3 times, etc. That is reasonably close to the binomial dist. we're trying to emulate. And we can get even closer by adding more balls.

Comment: Contrast this with a more naive model, where we have a bag with 12 balls in it, and there are 2 balls numbered "1", 2 numbered "2", etc. We draw 12 balls, each time noting down it's number then place it aside. For any given number the probabilities are: 0.00% for 0 times, 0.00% for 1 time, 100.00% for 2 times, 0.00% for 3 times, etc. That's exactly what we'd expect from a uniform distribution, but very far from what we'd see rolling a die 12 times in the real world!